# How to use variables in bash sed command, specific example

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to copy a section of a file to a new file.
If I use:

```
sed -n '1641,1804p' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

It works fine. BUT I want to replace the discreet numbers 1641 and 1804 with variables so I can use this code for different sized files. So I could have the variables instead:

```
$start=1641
$end=1804
```

I then want to pass these variables to sed. I use the following but it does not seem to work:

```
sed-n "$start,$endp" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Please help!

Comment: typo on line 12 I meant sed -n

Comment: chill out man I spent ages looking already and couldn't find anything that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "$" in front of the variables when you assign them which is incorrect.

To use shell variables that are concatenated with text or variables surround them with curly-braces so the shell knows where the variables end. In your example the shell is looking for the variable `$endp` which doesn't exist.

```
start=1641
end=1804
sed -n "${start},${end}p" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: This post was flagged for review.  I'm not sure if it's an answer or not but regardless I recommend adding a little explanation along with the code so that it doesn't get flagged and it helps the OP / others using this question. Remember questions answered are results given to others in search of answers for the same issue; so post with reuse of your answer in mind.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `sed -n "$start,$endp"`, the interpreter thinks you want to access the variable `endp`. You can fix this with braces, e.g.:

```
sed -n "${start},${end}p" oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use like below:-

```
sed 's|'"$start"'|'"$end"'|g' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```